# Windows 10 start menu entry missing that target same exe

Tags: windows-10, administrator, shortcuts, start-menu, elevated

I want two entries in the Windows 10 Start menu for the same application:
one for normal Start and another one for Start as administrator (elevated), so I no longer need to use the context menu.

I copied the .lnk in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and changed the properties to run it as administrator.

I expected to see two entries in the Start menu, but it only has one. It is the alphabetically sorted first of them. After renaming it shows the alphabetically first one again. Even if I add a command-line parameter to the .exe in one of the shortcuts I only see the first one.

Comment: There are two workarounds which allow quick start of either shortcut: 1st: Assign different keyboard shortcuts to each shortcut. 2nd: Hold SHIFT + CTRL when clicking on the entry in the start menu or when hitting enter in order to run it as admin.
But both don't answer the actual question

Comment: What happens if you rename one to `PROGRAMNAME - Run As Admin` or something similar? Windows probably does a duplicate check, and excludes shortcuts that have the same name.

Comment: I already tried different names of the shortcuts. Also similar as you suggested. In the start menu only the 1st one appears. I have Windows 10 Pro 1909 Build 18363.535 german.

Comment: Did you reboot your PC since you added them to the folder?

Comment: Yes several times. I have this problem already since months. Does it work on your PC? Or is this normal Windows 10 behaviour?

Comment: As I don't know which program you are trying to run, I don't know if it would run on my PC.

Comment: One possible solution für such problem is copy the target executable and rename it and add it to start menu with normal way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 Start Menu can't have multiple shortcuts with the same target](https://superuser.com/questions/1280211/windows-10-start-menu-cant-have-multiple-shortcuts-with-the-same-target)

Comment: @jw_: [this](https://superuser.com/a/1476344/603206) was helpful. The program is devenv.exe. So I could make a new shortcut to it and add the parameter /nosplash which does not change functionality. Now both shortcuts show up in the start menu.

Comment: @huha If you want you can put together how you solved this and post an answer below